# How do I know which services.yml is active?

Tags: configuration, 9

If I have multiple `services.yml` in the `sites/default/` directory, how can I determine which one Drupal is actually loading?

Is there a drush command to check this?  Or is there some other way to verify which services file is being used by a site?

Comment: I'm wondering how you can have multiple files with the same name? If you have files with different names you need to add them to `$settings['container_yamls']` in settings.php. You can compile the service container with as many yaml files as you want. For example modules can provide yaml files, too, which are loaded without settings.

Comment: @4k4 I was confused by this "Best practices" recommendation from the Site Audit module: Site-specific services.yml in use.

`Use of a site-specific services.yml is unnecessary for most sites, and can cause issues as it overrides core.services.yml. See https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2547447.`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The info is stored in global settings, but it isn't necessarily one file. To get the currently active list:

```
$container_yamls = \Drupal\Core\Site\Settings::get('container_yamls');
```